# Linux shell command source execute only with . call

Tags: shell, cron, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

On my ubuntu 18 server i create an .sh file like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "/home/ubuntu/.venv36/bin/activate"
nohup python manage.py runserver &
```

well, i save it as startup.sh in my `/var/www/web/core` directory.
At this point if in console I put my working directory like this:

```
cd /var/www/web/core
```

and execute

```
. startup.sh
```

all work fine, virtualenv get created and nohup start runserver.
the problem is if from root i call directly my script like this:

```
/var/www/web/core/startup.sh
```

command source does not run, but nohup yes, and finnaly my app does not work.
How can I execute directly my sh file? I need to execute it at server startup, now I use in crontab the command:

```
@reboot /var/www/web/core/startup.sh
```

but it does not work like I explain above.

Comment: Have you tried not sourcing  the "activate"-script but running your app directly with the python interpreter bundled in the virtualenv like:
`nohup /home/ubuntu/.venv36/bin/python /path/to/manage.py runserver &`
This was how i was doing it because virtualenv behaved strangely in scripts.

Comment: The way your program is written, it assumes that `python.py` is in the working directory. One possible explanation is that either the `activate` script does not set the working directory, or it sets it dependent on the the user or other dependencies from the environment. Antother possible explanation is that the `activate` script itself depends on the environment (or the user). Since you neither gave an error message, nor tell us about what's going on inside your scirpt, I can't make more than a wild guess. However, problems with cron are often caused by differences in environment.